# Why would an iPod Touch and PS3 respond to netdiscover as 0.0.0.0?

Tags: ipod-touch, backtrack, arp, netdiscover

Only slightly related to this question, because it was discovered in the same scan:

[Can someone explain how this happened?](https://superuser.com/q/357893/50086)

When running `netdiscover` on my home network, my iPod Touch (identified by DHCP-reserved IP address and MAC address) responded to both its own IP address on our 10.x.x.x subnet and to 0.0.0.0 also.  Why would this have happened?

**EDIT:**  After letting `netdiscover` run awhile longer, it seems one of the PS3s on the network is also answering to 0.0.0.0 - why is this?

Comment: Interesting.  I'll leave this for someone who may know more about the internals of these devices, but I would suspect some virtual interface exists that is replying, and doesn't have an IP defined. Perhaps a part of uPNP/DLNA.

Comment: Pretty sure uPNP is disabled on the PS3.  Don't know if that's an option for the iPod.

Comment: Does netdiscover give you a mac address for the two IP addresses?  Can you post them if so?

Comment: The MAC addresses given at 0.0.0.0 are the same addresses that answer to the systems' regular IP.

Comment: I wonder if this has anything to do with Apple's [Rapid DHCP](http://cafbit.com/entry/rapid_dhcp_or_how_do).

Comment: @daxelrod There's an interesting thought.  Does the PS3 have a similar feature?  It would be great if you could link to some documentation that specifically mentions the 0.0.0.0 ARP replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the article [0.0.0.0](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/workingwithipaddresses/g/0_0_0_0_ip-address.htm) :

> Computers normally show an address of 0.0.0.0 when they are not
>   connected to a TCP/IP network. Having this address, a computer cannot
>   be reached or communicate with any other devices over IP.
>
> TCP/IP software applications also use 0.0.0.0 as a programming
>   technique to monitor network traffic from any valid IP address. While
>   connected computers do not use this address, messages carried over IP
>   sometimes include 0.0.0.0 inside the header when the source of the
>   message is unknown.

Citing also from [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1) :

> The IP address 0.0.0.0 can have very different meanings, depending on
>   where it's used.
>
> - It's not a valid address to be given to an actual network interface,    along with any other address in the 10.0.0.0/8 subnet
>     (i.e. any    address starting with 0.).
> - It can't be used as the source address on any IP packet, unless this happens when a computer still doesn't know its own IP address and
>     it's trying to acquire one (classic example: DHCP).
> - If used in a routing table, it identifies the default gateway; a route to 0.0.0.0 is the default one, i.e. the one used when there is
>     not any more specific route available to a destination address.
> - Lastly, when seen in the output of the netstat command (which is what you asked for), it means that a given socket is listening on all
>     the available IP address the computer has; when a computer has more
>     than one IP address, a socket can be bound only to a specific address
>     and port pair, or to a port and all addresses; if you see an IP
>     address there, it means that socket is listening only on that port and
>     that specific address; if you see 0.0.0.0, it means it's listening on
>     that port on all addresses of the machine, including the loopback one
>     (127.0.0.1).

One possibility is a bug in the software on the iPod/PS3, forgetting to abandon the 0.0.0.0 address once a real address was granted by DHCP.

A more ominous possibility is that some software on these devices is listening to everything that passes on your local network. Even though a very tenuous possibility, I would not in your place logon to my bank website while these devices are on the network.